# Dataframe to text file in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently using this code:-

```
print(df.to_csv(r'tweets.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a'))
```

By this I am getting all the columns in the text file, but I only want a single column.Does anyone know how can I do it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just sub-select the col of interest:

```
print(df[col_of_interest].to_csv(r'tweets.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a'))
```

by doing `df[col_of_interest]` you only select that single column which will return a `Series`, if you want a dataframe use double square brackets:

```
print(df[[col_of_interest]].to_csv(r'tweets.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a'))
```

You can also pass a single list item to param `columns`:

```
print(df.to_csv(r'tweets.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a', columns=['col_of_interest']))
```

see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)